# How to call functions from another module in hook_language_negotiation_info()?

Tags: 7, hooks, i18n-l10n

I am writing a new custom module which is dependent on [geoip](https://www.drupal.org/project/geoip) module. I'm trying to add another language negotiation in the language detection configurations which would trigger a callback function defined in the module. Now How do I call the function defined in geoip.module file? I tried calling the function directly and after a module_load_include and both do not work.

```
/**
 * Implement hook_language_negotiation_info
 */
function my_module_language_negotiation_info() {
  return array(
      'geoip_language_provider' => array(
          'callbacks' => array(
              'language' => '_my_module_language_callback',
          ),
          'file' => drupal_get_path( 'module', 'my_module' ) . '/my_module.module',
          'weight' => -4,
          'name' => t( 'My Module GeoIP Negotiation Provider' ),
          'description'=> t( 'This redirects the user to correct language based on their IP.' ),
          'cache' => 0,
      ),
  );
}

function _my_module_language_callback() {
  module_load_include( 'module', 'geoip' );

  //Returns array of languages based on country code. Eg. array( 'CN' => 'zh-hans',)
  $languages = _my_module_language_mapping();
  $country_code = geoip_country_code();
  $default_langcode = language_default( 'language' );

  if( !isset( $languages[$country_code] ) ) {
    watchdog( 'geoip_language', 'The country code is not in the language mapping.' );
    return $default_langcode;
  }

  return $languages[$country_code];
}
```

Comment: Calling a function from a hook is not different from calling a function from another function. As long as you are sure you load the file containing the function, you are all set. What exactly do you mean by _do not work_? What error do you get?

Comment: The error I got was that function geoip_country_code was not defined even though the function is defined in the module. Tried it with module_load_include as well as without it.

Comment: I get you are using the 7.x-1 branch of the module, then.

Comment: Ah! Yes, using 7.x-1 branch. Didn't realize that there was a newer version available. I'll update and check the changes that have taken place.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the correct reason for this behaviour or not but it seems like the [language negotiation process runs before the modules and the themes are bootstrapped](https://books.google.com.sg/books?id=8I7IT0COId0C&pg=PA691&lpg=PA691&dq=language%20negotiation%20before%20modules%20initialization&source=bl&ots=xoFyKGHS1y&sig=0y2tzou3PjeAiS4102IMF_2_EFo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi9y_O7ma7MAhUJHI4KHbrcD3sQ6AEIIzAB#v=onepage&q=language%20negotiation%20before%20modules%20initialization&f=false://) in Drupal which would explain why the function is not available by default.

Changed the module_load_include to actually include the file directly by calling drupal_get_filename and requiring the file and it worked.

```
function _my_module_language_callback() {
  $geoip_file = drupal_get_filename('module', 'geoip');
  if( file_exists( $geoip_file ) ) {
    require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $geoip_file;
  }

  $languages = _my_module_language_mapping();
  if( function_exists( 'geoip_country_code' ) ) {
    $country_code = geoip_country_code();
  }
  $default_langcode = language_default( 'language' );

  if( !isset( $country_code ) ) {
    watchdog( 'geoip_language', 'Country Code could not be identified by IP.' );
    return $default_langcode;
  }

  if( !isset( $languages[$country_code] ) ) {
    watchdog( 'geoip_language', 'The country code is not in the language mapping.' );
    return $default_langcode;
  }

  return $languages[$country_code];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to read the module documentation to see if It provide a way to use It's own functions and instructions on how to use them. 
Also, you have to check if the function you're calling is in that module or in another file (for example, an inc file). If the function is in an inc file you can call it with something like:

```
module_load_include('inc', 'geoip');
// this cals geoip.inc
```

or like

```
module_load_include('inc', 'geoip.field');
// this cals geoip.field.inc
```

Comment: In this case the function is defined in the module's .module file. Ideally, I think we shouldn't even have to call module_load_include but even if we have to call it, it should be module_load_include('module', 'geoip') which is what I tried calling but it seems like it doesn't load the file as the function is still not found.

Comment: Have you read the module documentation to see If they specify how to call and use their functions?

Comment: Geoip is an API module and this is one of their api functions. This is what it says about this function: 
API function to return the country code for a given IP. Defaults to using the current user's IP if not specified. This function works with both the country and city level databases.

Answer (score 0):

Your language negotiation callback is called from [`drupal_bootstrap()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_bootstrap/7.x) before Drupal is completely bootstrapped; as such not all the enabled modules are loaded. In fact, it is called during the [`DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_LANGUAGE`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/constant/DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_LANGUAGE/7.x) phase, which is right before the [`DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/constant/DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL/7.x) phase.
You just need to use [`drupal_load()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_load/7.x) to load the module file as `drupal_load('module', 'geoip')`.

Keep in mind that your language negotiation callback is also called from [authorize.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/authorize.php/7.x), via [`drupal_initialize_language()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_language_initialize/7.x), the same function used from `drupal_bootstrap()`. If you are going to load that module in your language negotiation callback, be sure it works also when autorize.php is used from Drupal, which means when installing a module from the user interface, for example.